# Add file in apk so that user can access it?

Tags: android

I want to add my one file (example mp3) inside an `apk` so that when user start that application for the first time it should copy that file into phone memory.

Can someone give me some suggestions regarding how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the mp3 file in the assets/ folder. if your project doesn`t have one, create one on the same level as your res/ folder. Then, when the app runs, save the file to the sd card.

Answer (score 0):

Have try to put your file into raw or asset folders.because when AAPT packaging for .apk with .class then its focuse goes to res folders and then at last to manifest file...so when you puts your file into these folders then these files takes their space into .apk.
And use a variable to know your Application is installed for very first time then make folders(where you want) to copy that file...

Comment: I tried but it is not storing in phone memory... can u please provide me the code